# Using keywords instead of addresses to geocode points in R using Google maps API

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I've got a list of public buildings in New Zealand that I'd like to geocode in `R`, but no address per se.

I'd like to geocode using the name of the building rather than the address, since I don't have an address. I'm using the Google Maps API, but even reading the documentation, I can't figure out how to do [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#component-filtering) using `tidygeocoder`.

Below is the snippet that I've come up with. I just use the name of the building as the address and nothing else. ID #1 is geocoded as being in the UK, even though it's a building in New Zealand. My goal is to geocode this without touching the `name` field. The whole dataset contains more than 1,200 buildings.

```
library(tidygeocoder)
library(tidyverse)
library(mapview)
library(sf)
library(leaflet)

id <- c(1, 2, 3)
name <- c("Winchester School (P North) New Zealand", "Whangarei Hospital New Zealand", "Auckland Prison, Paremoremo Road, Paremoremo, Auckland 0632")
type <- c("School","Hospital","Prison")

df <- data.frame(id, name, type)

example_geo <- df %>% 
  geocode(address=name,
          method="google") %>% 
  arrange(desc(lat)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords=c("long", "lat"),
           crs=4326)
```

Comment: Are you using Google Maps API here? Together with leaflet?

Comment: Yes I am using the Google Maps API through tidygeocoder and leaflet. I'm open to using another package than tidygeocoder though. Do you know how to solve my problem using the ggmaps package for example?

Comment: If you are using google maps APIs for your app, I'd recommend that you use it all the way since from what I know, using it with other mapping services would be against their Terms: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=(e)%C2%A0No%20Use%20With%20Non%2DGoogle%20Maps.

With regards to your issue, have you tried using Places API of Google Maps?

Answer (score 2):

### Use `googleway` library's `google_places()` method

Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like a street address) into geographic coordinates (latitude and longitude), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map. But in general, use the Geocoding API when geocoding complete addresses (for example, “48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont, NSW, Australia”). If we want to Geocode ambiguous queries, in your case, just a keyword, it is recommended that you use Place Autocomplete or the Place Search of Places API. ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

> *NOTE: Before you start using the Places API, you need a project with a billing account and the Places API enabled. see [Set up in Cloud Console](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/cloud-setup) to learn more.*

In your use case, I believe the [Text Search of Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-text) would meet your expected results, and `googleway` library have this `google_places()` method wherein you pass in the `search_string` parameter and it will automatically use the Text Search of Places API.

You should check out the [Library's documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/vignettes/googleway-vignette.html#text:%7E:text=lng%0A1%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20144.9828-,Google%20Places%20API,-The%20Google%20Maps) to learn more.

Here's a code sample that simply shows that you can fetch the location coordinates just using a keyword using the Places API's Text Search in R language:

```
# import library
library(googleway)
# Put your API key here
key <- "YOUR_API_KEY"
set_key(key = key)
google_keys()

google_places(
  # I used one of your sample address here
  search_string = "Winchester School (P North) New Zealand",
  key = key
)
```

It will return this result:

```
$results
  business_status
1     OPERATIONAL
                                                  formatted_address
1 552 Ruahine Street, Hokowhitu, Palmerston North 4410, New Zealand
  geometry.location.lat geometry.location.lng geometry.viewport.northeast.lat
1              -40.3602               175.643                       -40.35885
  geometry.viewport.northeast.lng geometry.viewport.southwest.lat
1                        175.6444                       -40.36155
  geometry.viewport.southwest.lng
1                        175.6417
                                                                       icon
1 https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/school-71.png
  icon_background_color
1               #7B9EB0
                                                  icon_mask_base_uri
1 https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/school_pinlet
               name
1 Winchester School
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  photos
1 2448, <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117948596139985487361">Wajahat Ali</a>, AUacShjlzrLJfN5wAFz_m9XqIrnfq0-Hy9repJXZY_ZNnnfWxaF-k5OFX0D5lkChfAPonl8luXrqkoySaXZ3lTbs4l_VKHDOIERs04tukcYOYmgMaJ0zewGObt6IDvy3GG4tYiK4L6IdJnarftUW2C4QVdAES2WkuNUI0m_DumlTz95z88wV, 3264
                     place_id               plus_code.compound_code
1 ChIJ8xuN-veyQW0RKb1aOg-S0Jg JJQV+W5 Palmerston North, New Zealand
  plus_code.global_code rating                   reference
1           4VFQJJQV+W5      4 ChIJ8xuN-veyQW0RKb1aOg-S0Jg
                                                     types user_ratings_total
1 primary_school, school, point_of_interest, establishment                  8

$status
[1] "OK"
```

As you can see, it returns the correct location address in New Zealand and it also provides you the Latitude and Longitude coordinates in which the Geocoding should have returned.

I hope this helps!